# The uart on the FPGA is working half-heartedly. But it works correctly in simulation. Why is this so?

Tags: fpga, uart, riscv

I'm trying the dhrystone test on my risc-v processor in the FPGA. In the simulation, the fifo in the uart_tx module is working correctly. at first i was thinking maybe the tx wasn't being sent to the data what in fifo. But I typed uart_rx in testbench. But the testbench_rx was working perfectly. But I put my code in FPGA. I looking in uart console I just see  2 print(""); but when I send the code to FPGA. I see only 2 print commands from the Uart console. They skipped the print commands in between. In the simulation, this event works correctly. When I insert an FPGA it works half way. I'm running it at 20MHZ. I'm running 115200 baudrate. I using Zybo Z7-20 FPGA in this project

[UART CONSOLE TEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnI3Q.png)

[dhrstone's testcode's stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBzwm.png)

[Version Stage is working corrently in fifo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIe4r.png)

[Timing and implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eswe8.png)

[implementation warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kfPn.png)

I expect my application to work correctly in the console. I don't know what's causing the problem.

Comment: 1. Don't post the pictures of text, post the text itself.  2. Usually the difference between simulation and the real system behavior lies in failing timings (missing constraints, etc) or in metastability, when asynchronous signals were not properly synchronized in the target clock domain.

Comment: @Vlad I'm sorry about the first thing. I will research what you say on the internet. Do you have any simple advice in general for the vivado environment?